# How can I create a webapp with Spring (Tomcat server) and Maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I get the console message below when running my application but every time I navigate to http://localhost:8080/? I get an error message saying:

"Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jan 12 22:04:40 EST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)"

Console Output:

````
2021-01-12 22:03:17.212  INFO 21710 --- [           main] com.crd.carrental.CarRentalApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-12 22:03:18.343  INFO 21710 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-01-12 22:03:18.350  INFO 21710 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-01-12 22:03:18.350  INFO 21710 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2021-01-12 22:03:18.424  INFO 21710 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-01-12 22:03:18.424  INFO 21710 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1073 ms
2021-01-12 22:03:18.539  INFO 21710 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'clientInboundChannelExecutor'
2021-01-12 22:03:18.542  INFO 21710 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'clientOutboundChannelExecutor'
2021-01-12 22:03:18.548  INFO 21710 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'messageBrokerTaskScheduler'
2021-01-12 22:03:18.613  INFO 21710 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'brokerChannelExecutor'
2021-01-12 22:03:19.539  INFO 21710 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-01-12 22:03:19.541  INFO 21710 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Starting...
2021-01-12 22:03:19.541  INFO 21710 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=true, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [DefaultSubscriptionRegistry[cache[0 destination(s)], registry[0 sessions]]]]
2021-01-12 22:03:19.541  INFO 21710 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Started.
2021-01-12 22:03:19.551  INFO 21710 --- [           main] com.crd.carrental.CarRentalApplication   : Started CarRentalApplication in 2.977 seconds (JVM running for 5.797)
2021-01-12 22:04:18.616  INFO 21710 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2021-01-12 22:04:23.920  INFO 21710 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-01-12 22:04:23.920  INFO 21710 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-01-12 22:04:23.929  INFO 21710 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms```
````

Comment: Can you send the controller, it will be easier to debug then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have defined a `Controller` for the requested url `"/"` as below:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String homePage() {
    ... <your code>
    return "home";
}
```

And, your `home` page have to be stored in below path:

```
|--resources
    |--templates
        |--home.html
```

Answer (score 2):

white label error comes when there no page for that URL, you are searching. so in your controller see whether there is a mapping for "/".

Answer (score 2):

The White Error label is the expected behavior of an empty Spring application without any Controller Path. Unless you haven't configured any REST path or endpoint, this error will be shown.

If the error persist, make sure that your main application class extends the SpringBootServletInitializer and that you are writing the propery endpoint path.